# Cannot get_attribute('href') from element via Selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I've been stuck at this for eons now... Can you please help?

Trying to build a scraper that scrapes listings on [this website](https://ingatlan.com/lista/elado+lakas+budapest) and I just cannot for the life of me get the URL of each listing. Can you please help?

I've tried numerous ways to locate the element, this latest one is by the absolute XPath (by class always failed as well)

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import time

PATH = "/Users/csongordoma/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://ingatlan.com/lista/elado+lakas+budapest')

data = {}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Price', 'Address', 'Size', 'Rooms', 'URL'])

listings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.listing__card')
for listing in listings:
    data['Price'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.price')[0].text
    data['Address'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.listing__address')[0].text
#    data['Size'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.listing__parameter listing__data--area-size')[0].text
    data['URL'] = listing.find_elements_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[3]')[0].text
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)

print(len(listings))
print(data)

#   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[. = 'Következő oldal']").click()

driver.quit()
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 18, in <module>
    data['URL'] = listing.find_elements_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[3]')[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Many thanks!

Comment: It seems to be the second a[2] of listing  and not a[3]. Also use a relative path and not an absolute xpath. Then use get_attribute('href') instead of text.

Comment: your find_elements is returning no matching elements. Fix the xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below would work. To get a webelement of a[2] from an element and it's href.

```
data['URL'] = listing.find_element_by_xpath('//a[2]').get_attribute('href')
```